# Install virtualbox on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtual-machine

So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.1
```

And doesn't work, how do I install it..and I also have an image how do I run that..after I install virtualbox I just do `./image.vdi`

I have installed using this information from here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-4-x-on-ubuntu-11-04natty.html

I tried `./image.vdi`and I get this error:

```
./smon.vdi: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
./smon.vdi: line 1: `<<< Oracle VM VirtualBox Disk Image >>>'
```

I guess this is not the way you start it up..

```
root@ip-ip:/home/ubuntu/mt2/smon# virtualbox smon.vdi 
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.0.0-16-virtual) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Failed to open the X11 display!
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Well I had to do more steps, I've found this link: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-4-x-on-ubuntu-11-04natty.html and I'm installing it right now, but I don't know how to run/add the image after installation